# How to filter results by Collection?

Tags: low-search

Here is what I have as a working example of exp:low_search:filters tag on the result page and this works just fine. One can click on a category to show or hide entries for that particular category. Just wondering if the same can be done with collections? I mean can we show all the collections found in the query on the results page to filter results?

```
{exp:low_search:filters query="{segment_3}"}
  {exp:channel:categories channel="video" style="linear" category_group="11" parent_only="yes"}
   {if count ==  1}<ul class="category-filters">{/if}
     <li style="color: #fff;font-size: 20px;">
       <a class="btn btn-small" style="vertical-align: text-top;" href="{low_search:url toggle:category="{category_id}"}">
        {if category_id IN ({low_search_category})}
        <i class="icon icon-check red-icon" style="font-size: 160%;vertical-align: middle;"></i> {/if} {category_name}
       </a>                      
      </li>
    {if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
  {/exp:channel:categories}               
{/exp:low_search:filters}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally possible. Use the same principle as with categories, but using the `{collection}` variable pair to generate the collections. Pop this inside your Filters tag:

```
{collections}
    <a href="{low_search:url toggle:collection="{collection_name}"}">{collection_label}</a>
    {if collection_is_active}&check;{/if}
{/collections}
```

Comment: That's totally awesome. It's everything I hoped for! Worked like a charm. Much gratitude to you for this prompt response.

Comment: Low! Just one more favor. Can we limit collections to only those for which the results are found? Currently it shows all the collections I included in the first place within low_search:form.

Edit--
Can we use each and every parameter of the form tag in the same fashion?

Comment: That limit isn't possible at the moment, I'm afraid. You could show/hide them using the `{collection_is_active}` conditional. And yes, any parameter can be used with the toggle:-syntax.